# my C#/mySql product consumption query takes much longer time than the time tracked in the code

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, datagridview

I have a C# front end with mySql 8 back end for my company's database. I have a query that returns one month's production material consumption by way of material inventory and project process tracking. I have no problem with the query, but the time spent on the query (actually many queries).

This is the setup of my code, ran by clicking a label.

```cs
private void lblQry_Click(xxx,xxx)
{ 
   DateTime startDT = DateTime.Now();
   DataTable qryResults = new DataTable(); datagridviewResult.DataSource = qryResults.
   //set up qryResults as Projects vs. materials consumeds and cost associated,
   (I will skip the actual codes here, but it consists several foreach loops with many queries to 
   assemble the consumption and cost data per project...)
   
   DateTime endDT=DateTime.Now(); TimeSpan ts=endDT-startDT; 
   MessageBox.Show("Query time: " + ts.Seconds.ToString());
}
```

I have run this code many times, the results were checked and verified. But it takes a long time to finish and the time is so much longer than the tracking I put in the code, the pop message which showed about 20 - 30 secs usually, but the actual time when data appeared int datagridview after I clicked the label is on the level of over 10 minutes.

Please someone gives me some ideas as to where the problem is? Why these two times are off so much? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you mind hitting Edit, then select highlighting the code parts of your question and pressing the `{}` button above the edit box?

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign a DataTable to a datagridview's DataSource and then start filling the table; you could trigger a huge number of updates and refreshes to the datagridview. If your datatable contained a thousand items and you managed to trigger a refresh of the grid after every item item, it'll refresh itself a thousand times

Fill your table and then assign it to the DataSource

If you absolutely must make this assignment first, call BeginLoadData/EndLoadData which should turn off a load of stuff for the load. If you're still finding that the table loads in a few seconds but it takes the form 10 minutes to finish rendering its updates then we'll probably need to see more code to work out what is taking up the time

Comment: Thank you so much! I did assign datasource before the code runs, but at the beginning of the query code, I re-assign it to null. The problem was I assigned the datasource again after every new row added to datatable! I changed it to the very end and now the time is down to about 1 min. Thanks again!